# Rails 3: Register logs in model or controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, logging, model, controller

I have a Log model which registers some actions done to a Foo model. That means, every time I create or update a Foo instance, I have to create a new Log instance for its table to register the corresponding action. Where does this creation belongs to? To Foo's model or to Foo's controller?

I was thinking, in the model I can use the before_save method and that would keep my controller skinny, but I'm not sure if it's right to put that logic there. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logs can be used anywhere, it depends on your need to put them into right place.

For this case, your logging seems related to model changes but has little to do with HTTP requests, I think the better option would be model related place.

Option 1: `after_save` and `after_update` callback, not `before_save`. (You only want to log it after change already made effect)

Option 2: Model Observer.

I myself prefer Observer in this case because Log is not something inside this model so better not to use model callback. Also Observers allow you to add more things later easier. The downside is Observers are easy to be forgot, not a big deal if you can overcome it.

Comment: That was what I've been looking for. Thank you